# Csharp regex check If first and last character is “ '.-”

Tags: c#, regex

i don't want first and last this characters `“ '.-”`

this my regex

> ^(?!.*?[ '.-]{2})[\p{L} .'-]+$

Example

- `"Test"     match`
- `".Test"    no match`
- `"Test "    no match`
- `"'Test"    no match`
- `"'Test'"   no match`
- `".Test."   no match`
- `" Test "   no match`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I add this characters [^ '.-]

Regex final state

```
^[^ '.-](?!.*?[ '.-]{2})[\p{L} .'-]+[^ '.-]$
```